# C# Search for string in text file and return a different string

Tags: c#, text-files

I have many text files formatted like this:

```
tag(1008)<EX-->
------- Critical Item -------
Point taken at 06:00
NAME: OUTPUT_EXH_1_PLAN14_POINT3
Y       -43.842     -43.850       0.100       0.100       0.008       +     

tag(1009)<EX-->
------- Critical Item -------
Point taken at 09:00
NAME: OUTPUT_EXH_1_PLAN14_POINT4
Y       -43.825     -43.850       0.100       0.100       0.025       ++    

tag(1010)<EX-->
------- Critical Item -------
Y = ITEM 4
NAME: OUTPUT_EXH_1_PLAN14
Y       -43.838     -43.850       0.100       0.100       0.012       +     

tag(1011)<EX-->
EXH_1 Zero hole Cast to machine location
NAME: OUTPUT_EXH_1_CIRC30
Z         0.041       0.000       0.150       0.150       0.041       ++   
X        -0.035       0.000       0.150       0.150      -0.035       -     

tag(1012)<EX-->
Point taken at 06:00
NAME: OUTPUT_EXH_1_PLAN15_POINT1
Y       -23.555     -23.500       0.100       0.100      -0.055       ---
```

The actual text files may be several hundreds of lines (but less than 1000 lines). Above is just an example of some of the lines. I am new to C# and I have been searching online for hours for how to do what I want to do and have found many different methods... some seem simple... some seem complicated... I don't know which method is "better" for my application. Regardless, everything I have found either needs to be tweaked to do what I need or only shows part of the code I need and assumes I am skilled enough to figure out the rest. Can someone please help me by posting a complete working example.

What I need...

If the above text file is "D:\myFile.txt"

I want to search for the string "tag(1010)"

Then I want to get the first number after the "Y" after the string "tag(1010)"

So the number I would get would be "myNumber = -43.838"

As far as I have gotten was:

```
var myString = File.ReadAllLines("D:\myFile.txt")
    .SkipWhile(myString => !myString.Contains("tag(1010)<EX-->"))
    .Skip(1) // optional
    .TakeWhile(myString => !myString.Contains("tag(1011)<EX-->h"));
```

Then I was going to try to add more code to extract the "-43.838" out of myString... But of course the above code doesn't work.

Comment: The first number after `"tag(1010)"` is `"4"`, not `"-43.838"`. Do you mean the second number? Or something else, perhaps the first number after `"NAME:"` after `"tag(1010)"`?

Comment: You can load the file as a string using `var fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);` and then use `IndexOf` to find the first index of the string you're looking for, and then just parse the string for a number after that index. Please show what you have so far so we can help where it's broken.

Comment: Sorry I meant after the Y on this line: "Y       -43.838     -43.850       0.100       0.100       0.012       +" the line will always be a "Y" by itself followed by 7 spaces... then the number I need.

Comment: So if the tag was `"tag(1011)"` you want the number `"-23.555"` (which is the same as the number for `"tag(1012)"`, because there is no `Y` after the `"tag(1011)"`)?

Comment: No... ultimately I will want "0.041" for the "tag(1011)" Z and "-0.035" for "tag(1011)" X... And lots of tags and lots of other stuff but for right now... I only need "tag(1010)" and it will always be a "Y" and will always be a negative 5 digit number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    string myNumber = input.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)                                           
                           .SkipWhile((str) => !str.Trim().StartsWith("tag(1010)"))
                           .FirstOrDefault((str) => str.Trim().StartsWith("Y"))
                           .Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```

Replace `input` in `input.Split`

This will split by newline, skip all lines until it finds tag(1010), Find and returns the next line starting with Y, splits on spaces and returns the 2nd item `[1]` as the first will be the Y we split on.

Comment: ok... I am going to go try this... might take me a min...

Comment: Ive tried to make it look a bit cleaner, hopefully its easier to read in visual studio :)

Comment: Replace input with what?... Like... "var myString = File.ReadAllLines("D:\myFile.txt")"...? then replace input with "myString"...?

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice you were reading all lines. just use `File.ReadAllText("D:\myFile.txt")` but yes just replace input with it

Comment: says cannot convert from string to char

Comment: I have.... string myNumber = File.ReadAllText(filePath.FullPath).Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Comment: Sorry I'm using .Net Core, 2 seconds i will update the answer

Comment: Ok... That seems to do the trick... But I changed ".StartsWith("Y"))" to "StartsWith("Y   
    "))"... Basically thats "Y" with 7 spaces... well... I typed 7 spaces... stackoverflow deleted 6 of them...

Comment: Also... ".Net Core"... Should I be using this?

Comment: Unless you're doing cross-platform it likely won't have much of an effect on your code. It has a few extra built in methods which is what led to the confusion earlier. If you use Linq a lot I would recommend it but its set to replace .Net Framework from version 5 anyways.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five on the left you can go through the different versions and see whats new. It's still c# its just got a few extra bells and whistles, nothing too life changing.